# Relative spherical coordinates of 2 points.

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I have 2 points in space, defined by their spherical coordinates.

I'd like to know the spherical coordinates of the second point in a reference system centered on the first point (I know the unit vector defining x,y, and z in the new reference system, obviously).

Is there a standard way to calclate the new coordinates, without having to convert to/from cartesian first?

Comment: I tried this a few weeks ago using only geometry and gave up because it was taking too long. I think you have to use cartesians and then change it back to spherical polars (at least, I couldn't see any other way). I got 3 horrible equations, one for each coordinate. By the end of it all, I forgot what I had set out to do in the first place... so I am interested... do you know why you are doing this?

Comment: I'm currently working on augmented reality, and our current approach involves a lot of approximations, and conversions (and loss of precision). If we could get the points in the viewer's coordinate system, calculations would be much easier / faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason not to use the standard intermediate Cartesian coordinates.
The two points in Cartesian are
$$
{\bf x}_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}r_1\cos\phi_1\sin\theta_1 \\ r_1\sin\phi_1\sin\theta_1 \\ r_1\cos\theta_1\end{array}\right),
$$
$$
{\bf x}_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}r_2\cos\phi_2\sin\theta_2 \\ r_2\sin\phi_2\sin\theta_2 \\ r_2\cos\theta_2\end{array}\right),
$$
with the obvious convention that $\theta$ are angular distances to the pole.
The cartesian coordinates of the 2nd centered on the 1st:
$$
{\bf x}_{12}\equiv
{\bf x}_2-{\bf x}_1=
\left(\begin{array}{c}r_2\cos\phi_2\sin\theta_2-r_1\cos\phi_1\sin\theta_1\\
r_2\sin\phi_2\sin\theta_2 -r_1\sin\phi_1\sin\theta_1\\ 
r_2\cos\theta_2-r_1\cos\theta_1
\end{array}\right)
$$
The distance is of the new coordinate is
$$
r_{12} = \surd(r_1^2+r_2^2 
-2r_1r_2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2
-2r_1r_2\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)).
$$
The polar angle of the new coordinate is
$$
\theta_{12} = \arccos\frac{r_2\cos\theta_2-r_1\cos\theta_1}{r_{12}}.
$$
The azimuth angle of the new coordinate is
$$
\phi_{12} = \arctan\frac{r_2\sin\phi_2\sin\theta_2 -r_1\sin\phi_1\sin\theta_1}{r_2\cos\phi_2\sin\theta_2-r_1\cos\phi_1\sin\theta_1},
$$
taking the correct branch here...